# React Native Custom font Picker (Android)

Tags: react-native

Hi I want to set a custom font I downloaded to the react-native Picker component.
Any idea or solution how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0):

React Native currently doesn't support much styling for Picker component. You can use the itemStyle prop for styling the items on IOS, but it's not supported on Android yet. You can also change the color of the items with the color prop.

```
<Picker 
  itemStyle={ style.items }  // works only on IOS
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>

  <Picker.Item color='#000' label="something" value="something" />
  <Picker.Item color='#000' label="something" value="something" />

</Picker>
```